# What is the pattern of this type of Date?

Tags: java

I am trying to parse a string to Date, and I just need to find the pattern of this type of date below:

2016-09-07T02:03:30.000+03:00

I looked all of the patterns [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYBqS.png). I tried this one "2001-07-04T12:08:56.235-07:00" but it did not work. When I try to debug from the console (Because I am making a plug-in for software so can not have the opportunity to run code with just clicking run button), it did not give an error.

I used this code to parse:

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
Date date1 = format.parse(startTimeList.get(1));
```

So anyone knows the pattern of this?

Thanks a lot

Comment: That is the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date format. What do you mean with "It did not work"?

Comment: How do you figure it didn't work? Seems to work just fine.

Comment: did you just (before edit) have something like new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX;"); with ";" inside . try removing ";" from that and it should look like this new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");

Comment: @Jesper i mean when i try to print it there were no message.

Comment: @Kayaman Because it did not print anything.

Comment: @RajuSharma No there were no ";" in code. I just added the code when i edit.

Comment: Can you post a [mcve]?

Comment: @ErkanKarabulut Have a look at my solution, it's working.Use Joda-time and save time .

Comment: If it didn't print **anything**, your problem isn't with the parsing.

Comment: @mohitsharma Ok, that solved my problem guys. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Kayaman After the code above, i could not print anything. So it is about parsing.

Comment: @RajuSharma Actually i had a ";" there i really could not see. Thanks a lot. Sorry for posting these guys.

Comment: @ErkanKarabulut You can also achieve same thing in java 8 without using joda time , have a look at my answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use Joda-Time, It's a popular library and works like charm.
Steps to follow:

1. Add Jodatime to your project. Here [Download Joda-time](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time/releases)

   2.Add below code.

   ```
   String date = "2016-09-07T02:03:30.000+03:00";
   DateTime dt = new DateTime( date) ;
   System.out.print(dt.toDate());
   ```

My Output:
Wed Sep 07 04:33:30 IST 2016

Comment: I solved problem but just discovered Joda-Time and i think this is so much easier than the other one. Thanks

Comment: who did downvote my answer, please clarify if I've put something wrong??

Comment: @ErkanKarabulut please upvote or accept the answer if you it helps

Comment: If you are using Java 8 or newer, use the built-in `java.time` classes - you don't need Joda Time.

Answer (score 0):

**Java 8 way**:
If you don't want to use any external library like joda time you can do this:

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.Date;

public class DateParse {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2016-11-01T16:51:35.000Z" );
        Date newDate = Date.from(instant);
        System.out.print(newDate);

    }


}
```

My Output is:

```
  Tue Nov 01 22:21:35 IST 2016
  Process finished with exit code 0
```

Note: Be Careful while importing for Instant because Joda-time also provides Instant Class.